# Something is wrong with my javascript script with arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

so basically my javascript array script looks like -

```
cars = $('#bike').val();
var priceone = document.documentElement.getAttribute('priceone');
var pricetwo = document.documentElement.getAttribute('pricetwo');
var pricethree = document.documentElement.getAttribute('pricethree');
var pricefour = document.documentElement.getAttribute('pricefour');
var pricefive = document.documentElement.getAttribute('pricefive');
var pricesix = document.documentElement.getAttribute('pricesix');
var priceseven = document.documentElement.getAttribute('priceseven');
var priceeight = document.documentElement.getAttribute('priceeight');
var pricenine = document.documentElement.getAttribute('pricenine');
var priceMatrix = {
    cars: {
        1: {
            t1: priceone,
            t2: pricetwo,
            t3: pricethree
        },
        2: {
            t1: pricefour,
            t2: pricefive,
            t3: pricesix
        },
        3: {
            t1: priceseven,
            t2: priceeight,
            t3: pricenine
        }
    }
};
```

Maybe anyone have an idea, why the priceMatrix array, doesn't work? How should I insert all the variables into array, so it would work? The cars: is variable cars defined at top of the script and the priceone, pricetwo... pricenine are variables that are defined at top too. Hope you can help. If possible please write, how should I define var cars in javascript mode, so it takes the select fields value too. Here is the script, so you can cehck it - http://jsfiddle.net/tSsvb/2/ .

Comment: I'm not sure what `document.documentElement.getAttribute('priceone')` is supposed to do - are you setting such (invalid) attributes on the `<html>` tag?

Comment: Nope. I'mt rying to get the attribute pricone from the option field. Check the jsfiddle code. If possible, please edit it, since I'm not very good at javascript/jquery.

Comment: document.documentElement is html ! u r trying to retrieve attributes form html tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed : http://jsfiddle.net/tSsvb/20/

```
var priceMatrix;

function bikechange(){
    cars = $('#bike option:selected');
    var priceone = cars.attr('priceone');
    var pricetwo = cars.attr('pricetwo');
    var pricethree = cars.attr('pricethree');
    var pricefour = cars.attr('pricefour');
    var pricefive = cars.attr('pricefive');
    var pricesix = cars.attr('pricesix');
    var priceseven = cars.attr('priceseven');
    var priceeight = cars.attr('priceeight');   
    var pricenine = cars.attr('pricenine');   

    cars = cars.val();
    priceMatrix = eval('(' +"{"+cars+": {1: {t1: priceone, t2: pricetwo, t3: pricethree}, 2: {t1: pricefour, t2: pricefive, t3: pricesix},3: {t1: priceseven, t2: priceeight, t3: pricenine}}}"+')');
}
```

then:

```
 $('.recalc').change(function() {
        bikechange();  //call bikechange function here
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: But the price is not calculating, try changing the dates.

Comment: Hmm, something is still wrong on my version, maybe you have any skype/messenger via which I could send you the file, so you could check what is the problem?

Comment: @VdasDorls just copy the one in jsfiddle

Comment: It gives me error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Test car' of undefined

Comment: @VdasDorls there no `Test car` in the script

Comment: Hmm, and what should I do then? There is a test car in option value. ;(! I'm not able to post the script, since there's html table (huge one + php scripts.)

Comment: Okay, I forgot to add bikechange() function to the bottom. But now it says - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
bikechange
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.handlejquery.min.js:3001
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle

Comment: @VdasDorls just do like i did, create bikechange function that have `cars = $('#bike option:selected');
    var priceone = cars.attr('priceone');.............`

Comment: Check out this is the code - http://paste.php.lv/c082ebf1927bcf637ff13973c498ae19?lang=php . It's not workign for me.

Comment: add this `$(document).ready(function(){$('#cars_input').change();})`

Comment: @VdasDorls add at the end instead of `$('#cars_input').change();`

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Price matrix isn't atually defined as an array in your code, it is defined as a JSON object.

a JSON array would look like this with square brackets (cars is the array in the following code):

```
var priceMatrix = {
    cars: [
        {
            t1: priceone,
            t2: pricetwo,
            t3: pricethree
        },
        {
            t1: pricefour,
            t2: pricefive,
            t3: pricesix
        },
        {
            t1: priceseven,
            t2: priceeight,
            t3: pricenine
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: +1 I was often tripped up by this very issue when learning JSON.

Answer (score -1):

priceMatrix is not an array, is an object since it uses the { ... } syntax, not [ ... ].

Using objects, an integer by itself is not a valid property name. You need to change '1', '2', '3' to something else for it to work.

If you want to use this object in your code, you would access it's properties using one of these syntax:

Dot Notation

```
var firstCar = priceMatrix.cars.first;
// firstCar is now an object containing 3 properties, t1, t2, and t3
```

or bracket notation

```
var firstCar = priceMatrix['cars']['first'];
// firstCar is now an object containing 3 properties, t1, t2, and t3
```

fiddle demo of how to interact with this object: http://jsfiddle.net/cjDd9/

Answer (score -1):

Part of your problem comes from the difference between `Arrays` and `Objects` in JavaScript. You don't actually have a single array in the code you posted. `priceMatrix` is an object, as is `cars`, as is `1`, `2`, and `3`. Array syntax in JS uses square brackets `[]` as opposed to curly ones `{}`, which are used for objects. Although you didn't explicitly say it, you're surely getting invalid syntax errors because object properties can not be numbers (`1`, `2`, and `3`) in the code you posted.

On a certain level, you can think of arrays as normal, indexed arrays (i.e. whose elements may be accessed via their index number like 1, 2, or 3) while JS objects act as associative arrays (i.e. its elements may be accessed via a string, like 't1'). This is a gross over-simplification, but it may help sort out your current issue.

Having said all that, there is clearly another issue with the code in your fiddle. If you open your console, you'll see that you get an error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

That occurs on this line:

```
console.log(days + ' days in season ' + season + ' at ' + priceMatrix[bike][season][tier] + '/day (' + tier + ')')
```

If you log simply the value of the `bike` variable, you'll see that it equals `bike1`. So you're trying to access `priceMatrix.bike1`. But that doesn't exist. `priceMatrix.cars` DOES exist, but not `priceMatrix.bike1`.

Anyway, I'm not sure what your final goal is so I can't say that the following will totally solve it, but it does at least remove the errors:

```
var priceMatrix = {
    bike1: [
        { t1: priceone, t2: pricetwo, t3: pricethree},
        { t1: pricefour, t2: pricefive, t3: pricesix},
        { t1: priceseven, t2: priceeight, t3: pricenine}
    ]    
};
```

I've changed `cars` to `bike1` here since that is the property the `console.log` is trying to access. I've also turned `priceMatrix.bike1` into an array (note the square `[]` brackets rather than the curly ones, as well as the omission of any property names (like `1`, `2`, `3`).

Here's a link to the updated fiddle that does not produce any JS errors: http://jsfiddle.net/tSsvb/16/

Comment: But the price is not calculating, try changing the dates.

Comment: It should calculate the price, so changing the dates, the price would automatically calculate. You can see here - http://jsfiddle.net/tSsvb/1/ that it's calculating. But when I add the pricetwo variables it doesn't calculate anymore.

Comment: Ok, I didn't say that I fixed every error in your code. It's a lot of code with a number of substantial mistakes and I'm not going to debug every one. I imagine that's why no one else has posted a totally working example either. As an aside, I sure hope you aren't the one going around downvoting all the answers on this post...